Branch and bound problem, how to enumerate all of the possibilities?
Here is a problem that was in a past exam for Advanced algorithms in my studies,it's on 5 points over 3 hours so should take approximately 1H but I am struggling to find the solution for the first question.
we have n>= 2 elephants, each represented by a triplet: (weight(i), intelligence(i), cost(i)), where weight, intelligence, and cost are unique for each elephant. The goal is to find a subset S of elephants satisfying two conditions:

For all i, j in S, weight(i) < weight(j), <=> intelligence(i) < intelligence(j).
Maximize the sum Σ cost(i) for all i in S.




Elephant
i
Weight
Intelligence
Cost




1
1
2300
7
10


2
2
2000
14
80


3
3
2800
13
40


4
4
2100
11
50


5
5
2500
6
20


6
6
2600
9
15



Question 1 : Use a branch and bound solution to find the optimal solution by enumerating all of the possibilities
I have tried to do something like this
I just don't have the first for loop :( (or while loop i don't know)
On this code snipped i lack the first for loop
    S = [ [2300, 7,10], [2000, 14,80], [2800, 13,40], [2100, 11,50], [2500, 6,20], [2600, 9,15] ]

    solution = [ [i] for i in range(1,7)]
#for loop here 
    for i in range(len(S)):

        for j in range(i+1, len(S)):

            if (S[i][0] < S[j][0] and S[i][1] < S[j][1]) or (S[i][0] > S[j][0] and S[i][1] > S[j][1]) : 

                solution.append( [ i+1, j+1 ])

        solution.pop(0)


Expected output :
[[1,3], [1,6], [3,4], [3,5], [3,6], [5,6], [1,3,6],[3,5,6]]

If i do it on the given example, i wanted my "solution" at first loop first iteration to end like this :

solution = [ [1,3] , [1,6] , [3,4], [3,5], [3,6], [5,6]]

then for second iteration we only check and add the combination that already exist :
so for [1,3] i would try to add 4, then 5, then 6 since [3,4], [3,5] and [3,6] exist
for [3,5] i would try to add 6 , since [5,6] exist
This smells a lot like a recursive but i don't know how to translate it into code :'(((((
I don't even know if this is the right approach to this problem :(
Any help would be greatly appreciated, tips about how to find the solution, what is the solution, or some corrections to what i have done
Thanks a lot and have a great day !

This is too broad. Asking for "any help" is way too broad. You have at least two questions. Please only focus on one question in one post. Also, someone with visual impairments will not have an easy way to access the text on that image. Also that text is (currently) not searchable. Please type the text instead of posting an image of text.

I edited the post with the text typed + the example in the table + i only ask for some help on the first question :
Either a solution, a correction of my solution, or tips to correct my solution
Thanks :)

The title of your question mentions dynamic programming and branch and bound, and the image also shows the two distinct questions. Please focus on one question only: is it the branch and bound question or the dynamic programming question? Remove the image, and make sure all text is there that is needed to understand the single problem. Also the Python code you provided does not compile. You have opening square brackets that don't close. What is the ?? What is the purpose of S.pop(0)? The loop seems to add pairs to solution. What if the solution consists of three selections?

I edited the problem again, my solution doesn’t work because the first loop isn’t coded and I don’t know how to translate it into code. I want my solution to first find the pairs, then add the « possible » triplets thanks to my pairs ( if the pair (1,3) (1,5) (3,4) and (5,6) exist I try (1,3,4) (1,5,6) but I don’t need to try (1,3,5) since (3,5) doesn’t exist in my solution at first iteration (it’s the pruning step) thanks for the try though

Why not at least take care that the code compiles, and fix the syntax error?

Also, the line S = [ [w0, t0,n0], ...., [wn,tn,cn]] should better be the actual initialisation. And please add the expected output of the program for that particular input.

Yes it's all good now, thanks for the follow up

Why is the expected result a list of pairs? In the text you say that
"The goal is to find a subset S of elephants satisfying two conditions", but that expected result you provided has many subsets.

Also, more fundamentally, you write "Use a branch and bound solution to find the optimal solution by enumerating all of the possibilities", but by definition of "branch and bound": Before enumerating the candidate solutions of a branch, the branch is [...] discarded if it cannot produce a better solution than the best one found so far by the algorithm.", which means some candidate solutions are not enumerated in this algorithm. That is a contradiction. Please clarify what you mean with "branch and bound".

Honestly, this is the exact text of the exam, I can’t help you more than this :( I am also wondering what he exactly means by branch and bound here, maybe any solution would be accepted ?

For the subset, we want to find the one with maximum cost, so we would take [3,4] here but I only want all of the possible subset, I can code the other part

So you just want all "branch" and no "bound"?

Why are there no subsets of one element in your expected output? Surely a set with just one elephant complies with the given constraints? I would even say that an empty set complies with the constraints. Is there a rule that a subset must have at least 2 elements? Can you clarify?

Well, I just went ahead and posted an answer, giving two solutions: one with all possibilities, and one with a true bounding algorithm. The subsets with 0 and 1 element are also considered possibilities as that comes naturally. This may be important for when your input has just two elephants, but which cannot be combined in the same subset because of the weight/intelligence requirement. In that case the best subset will just consist of one elephant, i.e. the one with the greatest cost.

Too bad you never came back to these questions.

Your attempt will only find pairs, but a subset (by definition) can have any number of elements, from 0 to all of the elements. After excluding those that violate the rule on weight/intelligence, the subsets with 0 and 1 elements should certainly be considered valid. Also subsets could have 3 elements as is correctly depicted in your expected output.
A common approach is to use recursion.
In order to ensure the constraint on the weight/intelligence relation, it would help to first sort the input by weight. That way you only have to check the intelligence as you iterate the sorted list from "light" to "heavy" elephants. More precisely, when you have already collected some elephants (in order of weight), and want to add another elephant which has a greater weight, than it is enough to verify that its intelligence is greater than that of the elephant that was last added to the selection.
When you sort the list of elephants, it is important to keep track of their identifying number. This you can do by turning the triplets into quadruplets, where the fourth tuple member is the elephant's id.
It is confusing that the assignment speaks of "branch and bound", but then states: "...by enumerating all of the possibilities". This is somewhat in contradiction with what a branch and bound algorithm would aim to achieve, namely to avoid going through all possibilities, and attempt to stop looking further in a certain direction when it is already certain that whatever possibility is found there, it cannot be better than what we have already found as a candidate.
So I will answer your question in two ways:
1. Visiting all valid combinations
def solve(elephants):
    # Preprocessing phase:
    n = len(elephants)
    # 1. Sort elephants by weight, and add their id
    elephants = sorted([*triplet, i+1] for i, triplet in enumerate(elephants))
    # 2. Initialise the best we have so far        
    best = [
        0, # total cost of best elephant sub-selection
        [], # the best elephant sub-selection
    ]
    current_selection = []

    def recur(first_elephant, min_intelligence, total_cost):
        # If there are no more elephants, check if we have a better selection and backtrack
        if first_elephant >= n:
            print(f"valid combination: {current_selection}")
            if total_cost > best[0]:
                best[:] = [total_cost, current_selection[:]]
            return
            
        _, intelligence, cost, elephant_id = elephants[first_elephant]
        first_elephant += 1
        # Two branches to consider:
        #   1. select this elephant, but only if the condition is fulfilled:
        if intelligence > min_intelligence:
            current_selection.append(elephant_id)
            recur(first_elephant, intelligence, total_cost + cost)
            current_selection.pop()
        #   2. don't select the current elephant:
        recur(first_elephant, min_intelligence, total_cost)
            
    recur(0, 0, 0)
    return best[1]  # Return the selected elephants        

Here is how you run it with the example input:
elephants = [ [2300, 7,10], [2000, 14,80], [2800, 13,40], [2100, 11,50], [2500, 6,20], [2600, 9,15] ]
print("best subset:", solve(elephants))

The solve function has a print call so you can see which candidates are considered. The output is:
valid combination: [2]
valid combination: [4, 3]
valid combination: [4]
valid combination: [1, 6, 3]
valid combination: [1, 6]
valid combination: [1, 3]
valid combination: [1]
valid combination: [5, 6, 3]
valid combination: [5, 6]
valid combination: [5, 3]
valid combination: [5]
valid combination: [6, 3]
valid combination: [6]
valid combination: [3]
valid combination: []
best subset: [4, 3]

Note how this output also includes subsets with fewer than 2 members.
2. Visiting fewer combinations by applying a bound
A branch and bound algorithm will be able to sometimes forecast that extending the current subset with more elephants cannot lead to a better combination than the one we already have. This is really what the word "bound" is about in branch and bound.
To implement this idea, we would need to know what the maximum cost is that still can be added to the current subset if we would add all of the remaining elephants to that subset. This we can calculate as an additional preprocessing step.
Here is how the above program could be extended with that "bound" feature:
def solve(elephants):
    # Preprocessing phase:
    n = len(elephants)
    # 1. Sort elephants by weight, and add their id, and a cost running-sum (initialised at 0)
    elephants = sorted([*triplet, i+1, 0] for i, triplet in enumerate(elephants))
    # 2. Track how much cost is still available from a certain index onwards:
    cost = 0
    for elephant in reversed(elephants):
        cost += elephant[2] 
        elephant[4] += cost  # Accumulated cost for this and next elephants
    # 3. Initialise the best we have so far        
    best = [
        0, # total cost of best elephant sub-selection
        [], # the best elephant sub-selection
    ]
    current_selection = []

    def recur(first_elephant, min_intelligence, total_cost):
        # If there are no more elephants, check if we have a better selection and backtrack
        if first_elephant >= n:
            print(f"valid combination: {current_selection}")
            if total_cost > best[0]:
                best[:] = [total_cost, current_selection[:]]
            return
            
        _, intelligence, cost, elephant_id, remaining_cost = elephants[first_elephant]
        # Apply a bound when we cannot improve cost by extending the current selection
        if total_cost + remaining_cost <= best[0]:
            return
        first_elephant += 1
        # Two branches to consider:
        #   1. select this elephant, but only if the condition is fulfilled:
        if intelligence > min_intelligence:
            current_selection.append(elephant_id)
            recur(first_elephant, intelligence, total_cost + cost)
            current_selection.pop()
        #   2. don't select the current elephant:
        recur(first_elephant, min_intelligence, total_cost)
            
    recur(0, 0, 0)
    return best[1]  # Return the selected elephants        

Note how now the quadruplets are becoming quintuplets: an additional tuple member reflects the maximum cost that can be achieved by selecting the current elephant and all others with a greater weight. This is a ceiling we then use to apply a bound on recursion.
This version has the following output:
valid combination: [2]
valid combination: [4, 3]
valid combination: [4]
best subset: [4, 3]

Note how this improvement reduces the number of combinations that are actually tested for the example input.
Finally, in general a dynamic programming algorithm will solve this challenge more efficiently. As your question was about the branch and bound algorithm, that should be left as a next task.
